# Python: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am creating a program in Python to automatically backup my flash drive to. The first backup, it works great, but when it repeats the process to backup again, I get this error message.

```
File "D:\Programming\_Languages\Python\Automatic_Backup\Automatic_Backup.py", line 51, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(src, dst)
  File "C:\Users\carso\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shutil.py", line 303, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''
```

The contents of path_dst.txt are "C://Users//carso//Dropbox//Backup" (No quotes). The contents of path_src.txt are "D://Programming" (Again, no quotes).

I have been searching to try and find a solution, but I don't know how to fix this. Here is the code to the program, I would appreciate any help.

```
import shutil
import os
import time

with open('program_started.txt', 'r+') as program_started_file:
    # If program was previously started, runs instructions. If not, continues as normal
    program_started = program_started_file.read()
    if program_started == 'False':
        # Gets src path file and dst path file, write only
        src_file = open('path_src.txt', 'w')
        dst_file = open('path_dst.txt', 'w')
        # Gets src and dst paths
        src_path = input('Enter source path: ') 
        dst_path = input('Enter destination path: ')
        # Writes src and dst paths to txt file
        src_file.write(src_path)
        dst_file.write(dst_path)
        # Moves to beginning of document
        program_started_file.seek(0)
        # Writes 'True' in front of prevous 'False'
        program_started_file.write('True')
        # Removes 'False'
        program_started_file.truncate()
        # Displays 'Completed' message
        print("Completed getting source and destination paths")
    elif program_started == 'True':
        # Gets src path file and dst path file, read only
        src_file = open('path_src.txt', 'r')
        dst_file = open('path_dst.txt', 'r')
        # Checks if flash drive is plugged in
        while True:
            if os.system('cd D:') == 0:
                # Stores src path and dst path in string
                src = src_file.read()
                dst = dst_file.read()
                # If a 2nd backup has been made, removes first and renames 2nd
                if os.path.isdir(dst + "_2") == True:
                    os.rmdir(dst)
                    os.rename(dst + "_2", dst)
                    dst = dst + "_2"
                 # If only a 1st backup was made, creates a 2nd
                elif os.path.isdir(dst) == True:
                    dst = dst + "_2"
                # Copies data
                print('Backing up...', end='')
                shutil.copytree(src, dst)
                print('Completed')
                # Sleeps for 20 minutes
                for x in range(1,12):
                    print("Second: ", x)
                    time.sleep(1)
            else:
                # If no flash drive is detected, tries again in 5 minutes. 
                time.sleep(600)
    else:
        # Error message if program_started.txt != true or false
        print("Error: program_started.txt must only contain either 'True' or 'False'.")
```

Comment: Those are double forward slashes? Use double backslashes or single forward slashes.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried both of these and I get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already read and exhausted the file during the first backup, therefore an empty string is returned for future reads = Invalid path = `FileNotFoundError`.

You have to go back to the beginning with `seek()`. Place:

```
src_file.seek(0)
dst_file.seek(0)
```

after `while True:`.

If some files are read-only, it could prevent `rmtree()` from working. Define this function:

```
def remove_readonly(func, path, _):
    "Clear the readonly bit and reattempt the removal"
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
    func(path)
```

And then call `rmtree()` like this:

```
shutil.rmtree(dst, onerror=remove_readonly)
```

Comment: This solved that error but I now have another error. I get an issue using rmtree to remove the outdated backup. The error I get is "OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty" Any help on fixing this? I want to remove the directory and all of it's contents. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3af3c199a35d3d87281b669ecbfc6f8f) is current code.

Comment: @Crizz You can use this instead: `shutil.rmtree(dst, ignore_errors=True)`. It will cause it to ignore any errors and delete the non-empty directory anyways. This particular method will ignore *all* `rmtree()` errors though, not just your particular error, so be careful.

Comment: this causes it to just continue without deleted the directory.

Comment: this works as intended. I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the absolute path ,not the relative paths.

I have written a simple code for your help.

```
import os
import shutil

source1 = os.listdir("C:/Users/ved/Documents/source/")
destination = "C:/Users/ved/Documents/dest"


for file in source1:
   fname=file
   x=("C:/Users/Eccella/Documents/source/"+fname)  #for giving absolute path
   #print(x)
   shutil.move(x, destination    #for moving from absolute path to destination folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove white spaces from your path like:

```
path = your_path.strip()
```

Then it will work fine